# Spring Controller does nothing

Tags: spring, eclipse, controller, weblogic

Greeting my dear fellows

I would appreciate some help since I've been 2 days googling to find out why my code is not working. My webapp is Spring running in a Weblogic Server under Eclipse. Btw, apologies for my spelling (I am not native English speaker)

Straight from my webapp, the following controller **works flawless**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sendFile")
public ModelAndView vistaEnvioFicheros() throws myCustomException {
    ModelAndView model = null;
    try {
        getLog().debug("Setting model for sending a file");
        model = new ModelAndView("/content/sendFileWeb");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        getLog().error("Shxx happens: ", ex);
        throw new myCustomException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
    return model;
}
```

This controller loads a jsp file with a file browser button and a file upload button which **works great** too.

So when I click on the upload button the following controller triggers:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Object subirFichero(@RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file) throws myCustomException {
    
    ModelAndView model = null;
    
    if (file.isEmpty()){
        try {
            getLog().debug("File is empty");
            model = new ModelAndView("/content/errorWeb");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            getLog().error("Shxx happens again ", ex);
            throw new myCustomException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
        return model;
    }
    ...
}
```

**Problem is**: when I upload empty file, *errorWeb* jsp file should be shown in my web browser, however nothing happens. If I debbug the controlles I can see the code runs propperly until *return model* sentence nonetheless *errorWeb* jsp file is not loaded

Could anyone give me a hint about why first controller loads it jsp view but second controller doesn't. Also I don't get a single error message in any console or whatever

Thank you very much

Comment: Try to check file size instead - file.getSize()

Comment: I even tryed to reduce the code to this point but it does not load the second jsp web page:

@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile")
public Object subirFichero() throws myCustomException {
    
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("/content/errorWeb");
return model;
}

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it solved! This was just a newbie thing (I am a newbie web developper).

The problem was in the client side, where my webapp was sending the request thay triggers the second controller, **not** by an standard href o after a submit (or whatever), **but** by a custom javascript function.

This custom javascript function firstly validates the file and then uploads it to the server. After that client side code stops listening the response from the server. That's why the new ModelAndView is ignored.

Thank you for your time to all of you who read the post